# Grails createLink inside Codec?

Tags: grails, groovy, codec, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to write my own Codec which replaces entered data with a link to it (think of BBCode). I tried using `LinkGenerator`, but it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` saying `object is not an instance of declaring class`

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator

public class LinkCodec {

LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

def generateLink() 
{
    return grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller:'foo', action:'bar')
}

static encode = 
{ 
    target ->
    def map = [:]
    map.put("\\[link\\](.+?)\\[/link\\]", "<a href=''>\$1</a>")
    map.put("\n", "<br/>")

    for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) 
    {
        target = target.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString())
    }
    return target
}
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to find the bean as it may not do injection before your code runs.  I'm not sure the exact name but it should be something link:

```
linkGenerator = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grailsLinkGenerator')
```

Comment: Still getting the same Exception